# Limit type of arguments for concatenating BSTR

Tags: c++, windows, templates

So I wrote this templated variadic function `ConcatBstr()` to concatenate multiple BSTR strings.  
However, other users are calling it with arguments of other types than BSTR. Although this function could be made to accept WCHARs too, other string types are really not compatible with it.

**Q1**: How to properly limit the type of arguments accepted by `ConcatBstr()` to BSTR only ?

```
UINT LenSum() { // Stop condition
    return 0;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>    // General case
UINT LenSum(T bstr, Args... args) {
    return SysStringLen(bstr) + LenSum(args...);
} 

void AppendBstr(WCHAR* dest) {  // Stop condition
    *dest = L'\0';  //Add the terminating zero. SysReAllocStringLen() allocated 1 more wchar_t for it already
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>     // General case
void AppendBstr(WCHAR* dest, T src, Args... args) {
    UINT n = SysStringLen(src);
    wmemcpy(dest, BSTR(src), n);
    AppendBstr(dest + n, args...);
}



BSTR ConcatBstr(BSTR* s) { return *s; } 

template <typename... ADDTHIS>
BSTR ConcatBstr(BSTR* dest, ADDTHIS... addthis) {   
    UINT n = SysStringLen(*dest);
    SysReAllocStringLen( dest, *dest, n +  LenSum(addthis...) );  //Call this expensive function only ONCE !
    AppendBstr( *dest + n, addthis...);
    return *dest;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { //Usage
    BSTR s1 = SysAllocString(L"Quick");
    BSTR s2 = SysAllocString(L"Fox");
    BSTR s3 = SysAllocString(L"Jumped");
    BSTR s4 = SysAllocString(L"Over");

    wcout << ConcatBstr(&s1, s2, s3, s4) << endl;
    //I know that these BSTRs need to be freed eventually
}
```

**Q2**: Can this code be improved while retaining the property of calling `SysReAllocStringLen()` only once ?

Comment: From the compiler's perspective, `BSTR` is just an alias for `wchar_t*`, but *sematically* they represent very different kinds of data at runtime. You can use `std::enable_if` to limit your templates to just `wchar_t*` strings, but you can't differentiate between ordinary `wchar_t*` strings and actual `BSTR` strings at compile-time. So you have to be careful, you can't use non-`BSTR` strings with `BSTR` APIs, as they are going to be looking at the `BSTR` header that doesn't exist in non-`BSTR` strings. I would suggest writing/using a wrapper class for `BSTR`, then you can limit on that instead

Comment: @Remy: Does this mean, that I cannot write a separate version of  e.g. `LenSum()`, that will accept only `wchar_t*` argument and use `wcslen()` inside it to compute the length of the string instead of the BSTR specific `SysStringLen()` ...if  I wanted to pass `wchar_t*` as the e.g. 3rd arument to `ConcatBstr()`?

Comment: that is correct.  There is no difference between a `BSTR` and a `wchar_t*` *at compile-time*. While you can certainly write separate functions to wrap `wcslen()` and `SysStringLen()`, you would have to pass such functions into your `ConcatBstr()` so it knows which one to call. Otherwise, you *can* pass a `BSTR` to `wcslen()`, you just lose the speed benefit that `BSTR` provides by having its length stored in a hidden header that `SysStringLen()` reads.

Comment: That's bad news because my BSTRs have embedded nulls in them :(   I really wanted to  be able to write `ConcatBstr(&s1, s2, L"---", s3, s4)`?

Comment: All the more reason you should NOT be operating on raw `BSTR` pointers directly. Wrap them in something that is more type-safe (which you should be doing anyway, just for good memory management purposes), so you CAN differentiate between a `BSTR` and a raw `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1:** Not sure what you are asking for, as the compiler is already rejecting any attempt to pass an incompatible type as template instantiation will fail at some point. But you could use `std::enable_if` or `static_assert` to get a more descriptive error message.

**A2:** With C++17, you can reduce the code down to one function, using fold expressions and a lambda:

```
template<typename... ADDTHIS>
BSTR ConcatBstr(BSTR* dest, ADDTHIS... addthis)
{
    // use static_assert to get a more descriptive error message
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<ADDTHIS, BSTR> && ...), "tried to concant something else than BSTR");

    UINT n = SysStringLen(*dest);

    // use fold expression to sum up string lenghts
    SysReAllocStringLen(dest, *dest, n + (SysStringLen(addthis) + ...));

    // pointer to the next insertion
    WCHAR* ptr = *dest + n;

    // lambda appending the given string, incrementing ptr for the next invocation
    auto append = [&ptr](BSTR src)
    { 
        UINT n = SysStringLen(src);
        memcpy(ptr, src, n * sizeof(*ptr));
        ptr += n;
    };

    // use fold expressions to call `append` for every argument from left to right
    (append(addthis), ...);

    // append the zero terminator
    *ptr = L'\0';

    return *dest;
}
```

Note that the lambda is capturing the insertion `ptr` by reference, so every invocation will use the incremented value of the previous invocation.

Comment: however more logical use more simmetric signature - when function take several `BSTR` and return resulting `BSTR`. - `BSTR ConcatBstr(ADDTHIS... addthis)` not view any sense in `BSTR* dest`  in/out parameter

Comment: Re: A1.  I really wanted to be able to write `ConcatBstr(&s1, s2, L"---", s3, s4)`

Comment: @RbMm:  I wrote `BSTR* dest` because `SysReAllocStringLen()` requires it.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson but you not need `SysReAllocStringLen` at all. first call total len need by `UINT n = (SysStringLen(addthis) + ...)` and then use in `if (BSTR bstr = SysAllocStringLen(0, n))`